# Computing $\int_{|z|=1} {e^z \over z}\ dz$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

**Goal:** Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle. Then I aim to compute

$$
\int_{|z|=1} {e^z \over z}\ dz = \int_{\gamma} {e^z \over z}\ dz
$$

**Attempt:**

1. Consider that $\gamma$ is a closed curve.
2. Let $a = 0$.  Then $e^a = 1$.  Furthermore, $\gamma \cap \{a\} = \emptyset$.
3. We have by another theorem if $f$ is analytic inside some disk $\Delta$, and if $\gamma$ is a closed curve in $\Delta$ that does not intersect some point $a \in \Delta$, then

   $$
   f(a) \cdot n(\gamma, a) = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_\gamma {f(z) \over z-a}\ dz
   $$
4. Then combining the facts from above with the fact that $e^z$ is analytic on the whole plane (hence analytic inside any disk that contains the unit circle), we have that

$$
\int_\gamma {e^z \over z - a}\ dz = f(a) n(\gamma, a) = n(\gamma, 0)
$$

**Question:** Is my reasoning correct?  Is there an easy way we compute the exact integer value of $n(\gamma,0)$?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/358567/55235), maybe a duplicate.

Comment: You lost a factor $2\pi i$ in point 4. Your reasoning is correct, and in this case, using a natural parametrisation of the unit circle, you can easily directly compute $n(\gamma,0)$.

Comment: $n(\gamma,0) = 1$: the unit circle winds once around the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: do it explicitly for the function $f(z) = 1$.