# Evaluating: $\int^\pi_0 \cos(a(\sin(x))e^{a\cos(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate the following integral?

I don't know how to start...

$$\int^\pi_0 \cos(a(\sin(x))e^{a\cos(x)} dx$$
Where $a \ne0, a\in R $

Comment: I was tempted to close as a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358548/integrate-int-02-pi-e-cos-theta-cos-sin-theta-d-theta). You can adapt it easily. Or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409171/how-to-evaluate-int-02-pie-cos-theta-cos-sin-theta-d-theta?lq=1) for a solution which doesn't use complex analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Here is a sketch not a full solution)

Define $f(a)=\cos(a\sin x) e^{a \cos x}$. Take Laplace transform to obtain $$\mathcal{L}\{f(a)\}=\frac{s-\cos x}{1+s^2-2s \cos x}$$ hence 
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi}\cos(a\sin x) e^{a \cos x}dx&=\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\int_0^{\pi}\frac{s-\cos x}{1+s^2-2s \cos x}dx\}\\
&=\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{\frac{\pi}{s}\}\\
&=\pi
\end{align}

Comment: Naw; this is good enough. I too got $\pi$ after GitGud's links. Thanks for the confirmation... +1

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(a\sin x)\,e^{a\cos x}\,dx = \text{Re}\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp\left(a e^{ix}\right)\,dx $$
Now there is an easy way to evaluate the last integral, that is to exploit the Taylor series of the exponential function and the fact that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}_{> 0}$ we have:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\left(a e^{ix}\right)^n\,dx = \frac{i a^n}{n}(1-(-1)^n)$$
so the only term that survives to $\text{Re}\int$ is the one associated with $n=0$ and:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(a\sin x)\,e^{a\cos x}\,dx = \color{red}{\pi}.$$